# Who was the voice actor for this character?

Tags: megadimension-neptunia-v2

I was playing some Megadimension Neptunia and I'm at the point where

> Dark Purple

just appeared.

One of those "baby bugs" is speaking in the voice dialog (the character name is

> Buggie)

and my wife pointed out that he sounds a heck of a lot like "that teddy-thing from that one game you played", meaning Teddie from Persona 4 and it's remake/spinoffs. She's totally right, especially when the bug says "ohhhh...!" in a whiny voice you'd think it was Teddie if you heard it without context.

Sam Riegel did the English voice for Teddie but this Megadimension character is such a minor part I can't even find it credited anywhere after much Googling. Are there any voice-acting experts or superfans here that might know? I figure if Stack Exchange doesn't collectively know something, it's simply unknowable.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! I made the tag for you, and made a title. You can mark spoiler text with [>! before the line](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/editing-help), and it will be in a hidden block quote. I wasn't sure what to block out, since I'm not familiar with the series.

Comment: @DCShannon thanks for the tag and the spoiling help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A user on another video game discussion forum said:

> "I know when NISA made the new games they highered *[sic]* union voice actors outside of the union contracts. So they didn't list the actors names to protect themselves and the voice actors. 
>   I know this because I called their very friendly customer service line to ask them if Monica Rial was in the games they wouldn't tell me and they the union reason above"

While it's technically the conjecture of an individual based on his anecdotal experience, it's better than no answer at all and the reason does make sense.